# How many 20-digit numbers are there which are formed using only the digits 5 and 7 and divisible by both 5 and 7.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

now i realised last digit has to be $5$ and position of $7$ wont affect divisibility.
$$x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}x_{4}x_{5}x_{6}x_{7}x_{8}x_{9}x_{10}x_{11}x_{12}x_{13}x_{14}x_{15}x_{16}x_{17}x_{18}x_{19}x_{20}\equiv 0 \mod 7$$
so $x_{i}$ will be $1$ if it is $5$ and $0$ if it is $7$,so $x_{20}$=1.and then by remainder of powers of 10 i have to decide in which position $5$'s have to be placed.

so now its basically a combinatorics problem which i am unable to solve. please help.

Comment: Not sure about if there's a formula but surely can do by dynamic programming

Comment: by programming u mean by exhaustively checking for every case ?

Comment: No dynamic programming will make only 7*20 iterations which is very very small

Comment: even if you do exhaustively which is easy to write it will be O(2^20) which is also quite small and will give you answer in few milliseconds

Comment: yeah that i realised

Comment: yeah i guess i have to use programming

Comment: if you had programming related doubt in the question you could post on stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following generating function enumerates every 20-digit number using only the digits $5$ and $7$ and ending in a $5$.

$$G(x)=(x^5)(x^{50}+x^{70})(x^{500}+x^{700})\cdots(x^{5\cdot10^{19}}+x^{7\cdot10^{19}})$$

That is, $G(x)$ is the sum of $x^N$ for all such integers $N$.

If we reduce each exponent in this polynomial modulo $7$ and call the resulting sixth degree polynomial $G_7(x)$, $G_7(x)$ will be the generating function that counts the number of 20-digit numbers in each congruence class mod $7$. First (letting $\sim_7$ mean equivalence modulo “exponent reduction modulo 7”) note that $$G(x) \sim_7 (x^5)(x^{50}+1)(x^{500}+1)\cdots(x^{5\cdot10^{19}}+1).$$ Then note that the sequence $50\mbox{ mod }7$, $500\mbox{ mod }7$, $5000\mbox{ mod }7,\dots$ is the repeating sequence $(1,3,2,6,4,5,1,3,2,6,4,5,\dots)$, so

$$G(x) \sim_7 x^5\left((x^1+1)(x^3+1)(x^2+1)(x^6+1)(x^4+1)(x^5+1)\right)^3\cdot(x^1+1)\mbox{, or}$$

$$G(x) \sim_7 x^5\left((x^1+1)(x^2+1)(x^3+1)(x^4+1)(x^5+1)(x^6+1)\right)^3\cdot(x^1+1).$$

Mathematica easily computes $G_7$.

```
Expand[(x^5)Product[1+x^i,{i,1,6}]^3(1+x^1)] //.x^n_->If[n>6,x^(n-7),x^n]
```

$$G_7(x)=74898+74898 x+74898 x^2+74898 x^3+74898 x^4+74899 x^5+74899 x^6.$$

So the answer to your original question is 74898.

You could answer this question by hand, too with a bit of effort. For example, if you expand and exponent-reduce $\prod_{k=1}^{6}(x^k+1)$ mod 7, you get $10+9x+9x^2+9x^3+9x^4+9x^5+9x^6$. Square this and reduce again to get $586+585 x+585 x^2+585 x^3+585 x^4+585 x^5+585 x^6$, and so on. At the very end, you only need to find the constant term.

Answer (score 2):

The question boils down to the following: How many $x_i \in \{ 5,7 \}$ can you find such that

$$x_1...x_{19}5 \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$$

Since $7$ is divisible by $7$, we can replace all $7's$ by $0$s.

Define $y_i =1$ if $x_i=5$ and $0$ otherwise. So the problem boils to 
$$5\cdot y_1...y_{19}1 \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$$
or
$$  y_1...y_{19}1 \equiv 0 \pmod{7} \,.$$

As the powers of $10 pmod {7}$ are cyclically $1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5$, the problem becomes
$$(1+y_{14}+y_{8}+y_{2})+3 (y_{19}+y_{13}+y_{7}+y_{1}) + 2 (y_{18}+y_{12}+y_{6})+6(y_{17}+y_{11}+y_{5})+4(y_{16}+y_{10}+y_{5})+5(y_{15}+y_{9}+y_{3}) \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$$

Define 
$$a= 1+y_{14}+y_{8}+y_{2} \\
b=y_{19}+y_{13}+y_{7}+y_{1} \\
c=y_{18}+y_{12}+y_{6} \\
d= y_{17}+y_{11}+y_{5} \\
e=y_{16}+y_{10}+y_{5} \\
f= y_{15}+y_{9}+y_{3} (*)$$

Then the problem reduces to the following  simpler problems:

**Problem:** Find all solutions of 
$$a+3b+2c+6d+4e+5f =0 \pmod{7}$$
with $1 \leq a \leq 4 \,;\, 0 \leq b \leq 4 \,;\, 0 \leq c,d,e,f \leq 3$.

Now for each solution, when you look back at $(*)$ you have to figure out how many ways can you distribute the 1's among the y's. The problem becomes the problem of choosing in order $a-1, b, c, d,  e, f$ positions for ones out of $3,4,3,3,3,3$, so the final answer will be
$$\sum_{(a,b,c,d,e,f) \mbox{solution} } \binom{3}{a-1} \binom{4}{b} \binom{3}{c}\binom{3}{d}\binom{3}{e}\binom{3}{f}$$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $$(5 \times 10^i \pmod 7)_{i=0}^{19}=(5, 1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 1).$$  Since any such number must end in $5$, and since $7, 70, 700,\ldots$ are all divisible by $7$, the answer is equal to the number of ways of choosing elements of $$T:=(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6)$$ that sum to $2 \pmod 7$.

For a sequence $S$ and $m \in \mathbb{Z}_7$, define $f(m,S)$ to be the number of ways of choosing elements of $S$ that sum to $m \pmod 7$.  For $i \in \{0,1,\ldots,5\}$ define $T^{(i)}$ to be the subsequence of $T$ formed by deleting the elements $\leq i$.

We seek $f(2,T^{(0)})$.  We will compute this number recursively.

We observe that, for all $m \in \mathbb{Z}_7$,
$$
f(m,T^{(i-1)})=\sum_{k=0}^3 \binom{3}{k} f(m-ik,T^{(i)})
$$
for $i \in \{2,3,4,5,6\}$ and
$$
f(m,T^{(0)})=\sum_{k=0}^4 \binom{4}{k} f(m-k,T^{(1)}).
$$

This enables us to compute:
$$
\begin{array}{r|ccccccc}
    & f(0,T^{(i)}) & f(1,T^{(i)}) & f(2,T^{(i)}) & f(3,T^{(i)}) & f(4,T^{(i)}) & f(5,T^{(i)}) & f(6,T^{(i)}) \\
\hline
i=6 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
5 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 3 \\
4 & 7 & 10 & 12 & 12 & 10 & 7 & 6 \\
3 & 73 & 73 & 73 & 73 & 73 & 74 & 73 \\
2 & 585 & 587 & 584 & 584 & 587 & 585 & 584 \\
1 & 4679 & 4684 & 4678 & 4684 & 4679 & 4682 & 4682 \\
0 & 74899 & 74899 & \color{red}{74898} & 74898 & 74898 & 74898 & 74898 \\
\end{array}
$$

This can be verified using brute force: the [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) code

```
Size(Filtered(Tuples([5,7],20),A->Sum([1..20],i->10^(i-1)*A[20-i+1]) mod 35=0));
```

returns `74898`.